# How to activate disabled Gmail account with mobile number

Tags: gmail

My account is disabled due to suspicious accesses. I have forgot alternate mail id attached but my mobile number is attached with Gmail Account. Can I activate my account with the help of mobile number?

Answer (score 1):

If Google disabled your account, you should be directed to page upon login with general information about why and a link to appeal/recover the account.

**You can follow steps here: http://www.webesupport.com/how-to-recover-google-account-disabled-due-to-suspicious-activity**

> **Why Google disables accounts**
>
> Google wants to ensure that everyone has a chance to safely and securely connect and communicate. To help preserve this environment, Google reserves the right to:
>
> - Suspend a Google Account from using a particular product or the entire Google Accounts system if there is a violation of the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html), product-specific Terms of Service (available on the product page), or [product-specific policies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/147806).
> - Terminate your account at any time, for any reason, with or without notice.
>     **Next steps for disabled accounts**
>
> Please start by reviewing the relevant Terms of Service. Then, if you think your account should not have been disabled, please [**contact us**](https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/disabled2?p=mail). By contacting us to look into this issue, you certify that you’re the owner of the account and consent to allowing us to review the contents of your account to evaluate your request.

If the disable was in error, you will hear back and the account can be restored.

If you've simply forgotten or lost access to the account, you can go through the [Google Account Recovery](https://accounts.google.com/RecoverAccount) flow.

So mobile number work when you recover account, or when Google team will contact you after finding the error and ask to send mobile number or send any code to your register mobile number.